# SSRS How to get the value before the latest column of a matrix row group?

Tags: reporting-services

I would like to retrieve the value before the last column in the matrix. 
The column are grouped by Month and user can choose in the report one , two, three or more columns , the aim is to get the before last column value. 
For getting the last value I just have to do : LAST(filed!Value), how to get the value of the columns before the column containing LAST(filed!Value).
eg: If user choose january to december --> i want to get November value
If He choose January to march --> I want to get February value
I am working with ssrs 2008.
I hope my explanations are clear.
Thanks in advance for your help

LAST(Fields!ColumnN.Value) --> last column
??? --> Before the last column

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but there is also a `Previous` function in SSRS that should be just what you're looking for.  I don't know for sure if you can use these functions in conjunction, but I believe you could use the following expression:

```
= Previous(Last(Fields!ColumnN.Value))
```

Comment: Hello Steve-o169, I already tested this before posting question  but it is not working for me . thanks